# VBA Count rows until match string in another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to count the number of rows until a string is found in a certain column.
The string that I am trying to look for is found within the workbook that the code is being ran from. Then I am taking that string and trying to match it to a cell value in a column of a different workbook. The following code is what I have come up with, however, it always results in `i=0` even though I know that the string definitely exists within the other workbook.

```
    Set wkb = Excel.Workbooks("workbook1.xlsm")
    Set wks = wkb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    n = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, "D").Value
    i = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    i = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(n, wkb.wks.Range("A:A").Value, 0)
    On Error GoTo 0
```

I have tried to find similar problems online, however all of them work by counting rows in the same workbook. Any ideas of what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: The first thing to do is to remove the `On Error` statements, if there is some problem you need to see the error (or handle it). Does `n` contain the value you think it does? Print it out to check. Does it have any extra characters such as whitespace, and is it an exact match? Use MATCH in a cell to test.

Comment: You don't need `.Value`, the argument is a range. Removing the On Error statements should produce an error.

Answer (score 2):

The second argument to `Match` is a `Range` so remove `.Value`.

```
i = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(n, wkb.wks.Range("A:A"), 0)
```

Remove the `On Error` statements and an error message would indicate the problem. Do not introduce `On Error Resume Next` unless you have thoroughly tested your code and are convinced that any (anticipated) errors can be ignored. Even then, it should be used rarely.

---

Please also rename your variables to something useful.